# Build Web Apps using more than one database like http://sqlfiddle.com/

Tags: mysql, sql-server, web, server

I'm building a web apps to learn SQL Suery. I'm going to build the web like sqlfiddle where we can learn the SQL query more than one SQL Programming Language. I'm trying on MySQL and SQL Server. But I don't understand how to build them into one web apps. Any suggestion? Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about [Database Abstraction Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer).

If PHP is your programming language, you can try PDO as it supports more than a handful of DBMS's. Check [PDO Drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) for more information